# Fail to make post request with React native

Tags: react-native, fetch

Tried to implement nodemailer to my RN project, but I struggle at making basic post request. What am I missing?

RN code:

```
const sendEmail = (_email, _topic, _text) => {
    return dispatch => {
        fetch('http://MY_IP/api/sendEmail', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: _email,
                topic: _topic,
                text: _text
            })
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((res) => {
                console.log('here is the response: ', res);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error('here is the error: ', err);
            })
    }
}
```

server:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.post('/api/sendEmail', (req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send(req.body)
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

Im getting req.body is undefined.

If I need to post more code or add package.json please do let me know

Comment: You forgot to include `app.use(bodyParser.json())`

Comment: Okay, this is embarassing, you're right, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your RN code is fine but server code is missing body parser package. Install dependency "npm install body-parser --save" in "package.json" after that your server code should look like this

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/api/sendEmail', (req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send(req.body)
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Better use axios package, its easy to send post request to api.

Package Link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Eg:

```
  axios.post('/http://MY_IP/api/sendEmail', {
    email: _email,
    topic: _topic,
    text: _text
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```